# Special characters inside qbxml

Tags: php, quickbooks

In recent days I noticed that Quickbooks won't accept the em dash even qbxml validator says xml is valid.

Problem is I have a string like below:

**100 W. Randolph – Ste.4-100**

When I tried to migrate this customer using php devkit, I got this issue:

**QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream**

I tried to input this em dash direct to the quickbooks enterprise (v19) and it worked. 
I'm not sure what's happening here. How can I submit this em dash inside the qbxml so that quickbooks can accept it.

Comment: Is your data in `CDATA` tags?

Comment: Sorry I don't have deep knowledge about xml, btw during check about this cdata and qbxml I found this article. http://consolibyte.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=8626 It seems CDATA is working with Quickbooks. Thanks for your hint, @ArtisticPhoenix, let me check this and will post the result.

Comment: Sure hope it works for you, if not I have code that I can share that will convert them to `-` normal hyphens.  That's the fallback solution at least

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, could you post your answer with details so that I can vote your answer? I tested with CDATA and it also worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CDATA,

These are the weird tags you may have seen like this:

```
<Name><![CDATA[1234567 Steel Décor]]></Name>
```

Cdata basically means character data and is commonly a way to put things like HTML and other special characters in an XML file.  It tells the XML parser to ignore this content and treat it as plain text (basically)

Here is a link to the wiki page with more details then I care to type such as the history of it ect.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

> In an XML document or external parsed entity, a CDATA section is a section of element content that is marked for the parser to interpret purely as textual data, not as markup.

If you use the XMLWriter library to make XML there are 2 functions specifially for this:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xmlwriter.php

And more specifically

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-start-cdata.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-end-cdata.php

I have used these many times in the past and they work really well for most special characters etc...

Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure this works with QBXML? I just tried this with the following field: 

`<Name>![CDATA[Shore Home & Services]]</Name>`and received the following error on that line: 

`Error during validation: D, Conversion from string "Line: 9
LinePos: 29
Src Text: " to type 'Double' is not valid.` 

when I validated the XML using the QBValidator

Comment: That was a long long time ago.  So I cant answer that

Answer (score 2):

You have to encode special characters to send them to QuickBooks. e.g. if you're trying to send this:

```
<Name>1234567 Steel Décor</Name>
<CompanyName>Steel Décor</CompanyName>
```

You need to send this:

```
<Name>1234567 Steel D&#233;cor</Name>
<CompanyName>Steel D&#233;cor</CompanyName>
```

If you're using this PHP lib:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Then you can do something like this:

```
$encoded = QuickBooks_Cast::cast(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, 'FullName', $raw);
```

Per the example here:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/qbxml/example_qbxml_cast.php

Comment: What encoding did you use in your examples?